# I'm trying to communicate through I2C with a temperature sensor (STS21) using interrupts on STM8S003F3 board but i can't manage to make it work

Tags: i2c, stm8

I've been trying for some days to make this code work but I can't manage to do it. The variable in which I try to store the the temperature (which should be around 20-22 degrees Celsius), contains the value 4.82, which is far from the correct answer. I tried looking at the example code offered by ST Electronics, but still didn't help me. I'll post the main code and the interrupt one here maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

main:

```
#include "stm8s.h"

static void CLK_Config(void);
static void I2C_Config(void);
static void GPIO_Config(void);
static void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount);

static void CLK_Config(void) {
    CLK_SYSCLKConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_HSIDIV1);
    CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_I2C, ENABLE);
}

static void I2C_Config(void) {
    I2C_Cmd(ENABLE);
    I2C_Init(10000, 0xA0, I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2, I2C_ACK_CURR, I2C_ADDMODE_7BIT, 16);
    I2C_ITConfig(I2C_IT_EVT, ENABLE);
    I2C_ITConfig(I2C_IT_BUF, ENABLE);
    
    //B4 - SCL
    //B5 - SDA
}

static void GPIO_Config(void) {
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_MODE_IN_FL_NO_IT);   
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_MODE_IN_FL_NO_IT);
}

static void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount) {
  for (; nCount != 0; nCount--);
}

int x,i;
void main(void)
{
    CLK_Config();
    GPIO_Config();
    I2C_Config();
    enableInterrupts();
    
while (1){
    I2C_GenerateSTART(ENABLE);
}

}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *   where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval : None
  */
void assert_failed(u8* file, u32 line)
{ 
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif
```

interrupt:

```
float T;
int y;
uint8_t a, b;
uint16_t v;
INTERRUPT_HANDLER(I2C_IRQHandler, 19)
{
  /* In order to detect unexpected events during development,
     it is recommended to set a breakpoint on the following instruction.
  */
    I2C_Send7bitAddress(0x4A, I2C_DIRECTION_RX);
    y = I2C->SR1;
    y = I2C->SR3;
    a = 0;
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_FLAG_RXNOTEMPTY) == SET);
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C_ACK_NONE);
    a = I2C_ReceiveData();
    b = 0;
    while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_FLAG_RXNOTEMPTY) == SET);
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C_ACK_NONE);
    b = I2C_ReceiveData();
    b &= ~(1<<0);
    b &= ~(1<<1);
    I2C_GenerateSTOP(ENABLE);
    v = 0;
    v += a;
    v = v << 8;
    v += b;
    T = 0;
    T = -46.85 + 175.72 * ((float)v / 65536);
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to debug these issues without using a scope. Capture the SCL and SDA waveforms and compare against the temp sensor datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug this with method, it will be hard for us to find the problem. Check several things:

1. Is the value in T written during the interrupt? Is it 0 before the interrupt happens? Or is this just a random value, that happens to be in memory? If you are sure, that T really is written in the interrupt you can go one step further.
2. What values do you get in "a" and "b"? Do they contain the values you expect? If yes, your conversion is wrong. If not, the I2C readout does not work.
3. Does the I2C readout work at all? Use a scope or logic analyser to check the I2C lines. Compare with the data you expected on the data lines.
4. Depending on how the data on the I2C lines deviates from the expected values you can further narrow down the problem.

Debugging should always follow a logical approach like this. Try to narrow down the place where the problem occurs.

Comment: i'm weary of using a logic analyzer to debug i2c unless you have at least seen the real signal on a scope...

Comment: Yes I agree, seeing the shape of the waveform with a scope is preferred during initial debugging. But if no scope is available but a logic analyser is, it is at least something.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, i'm sure that T is written in the interrupt. "a" and "b" contain the same binary values, which i think is wrong. "a" should be MSB, and "b" should be LSB, the last two bits from "b" should always be 0 as it says in the sensor's datasheet. Lastly i think that my I2C readout is wrong because i can't think of anything else, but i don't know what i can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us anything about your circuit, but a lot of times I2C problems come down to something electrical. Most notably, the size of your pull-up resistors. I like to use 1.8kOhms, but you'll find people using 2.2k, 3.3k, and 4.7k in various contexts. The "right" answer to that depends on bus capacitance, but I'd start out at 1.8k and see if things improve.

Since you said in your comments in response to the previous answer the "a" and "b" were the same, are you sure you are following the protocol correctly for talking to the sensor? Sometimes you have to use a repeated start or something similar in order to automatically increment a read pointer in the sensor and so forth. You really need to see what's going on with a Logic analyzer at least, and then read the datasheet closely. Or look for existing libraries and see if there's some nuance you are missing on the method to read the sensor.